# Say whether the function f(x) is O(x)

Tags: functions

$f(x) = $$\lfloor x/2 \rfloor$

$|f(x)| \leqslant M|g(x)|$
$\lfloor x/2 \rfloor \leqslant (1/2)|\lfloor x \rfloor|$

What's next?

I have done simple equations for order notation. but this one has floor.

Am i suppose to use $\lfloor x \rfloor = n \leqslant x < n+1$

Answer (score 1):

We say a function $f(x)$ is $O(x)$ if $\exists x_0$, $x \geq x_0 \implies |f(x)| \leq M|x|$.

For $x \geq 0$, $$|f(x)|=\lfloor x/2 \rfloor \leq \frac{x}{2}=\frac{|x|}{2},$$

Hence $f(x)$ is $O(x)$.

Comment: that's it bwoii

Comment: Thanks. is $M = \frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: Yes, you can also pick anything that is bigger than that.